# ListArray returns an empty list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-mlkit

While using List, it returns the value of the list within the function, but outside the scope of a function, it returns an empty list.

```
public List<Rect> face_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void mlkit(FirebaseVisionImage image) {

    face_list.clear();
    Task<List<FirebaseVisionFace>> result =
            detector.detectInImage(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
                                   for (FirebaseVisionFace face : faces) {
                                        Rect bounds = face.getBoundingBox();

                                        face_list.add(bounds);
                                        Log.d("cns",face_list.toString()); // this returns face_list
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                }
                            });

        Log.d("cns",face_list.toString()); // this returns an empty list
    }
```

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener()` is being called asynchronously (and typically after `mlkit` function has returned.  You need to structure your app to respond to the async updates

Comment: If it's asynchronously called, how is it supposed to be real-time as the documentation promises it to be?
I'm looking for some real-time operation. Can you help me out here on how to proceed then?